# Data not being shown in table

Tags: java, cassandra

I tried to stress test my Cassandra, due to some reason my Cassandra-stress tool was not working on windows so as a workaround, I made a 100000 loop POST request to C*, the backend was in JAVA,

My cassandra table schema is:-

```
CREATE TABLE Stress2.demomodel(acctID TEXT, transactionDate Date , card TEXT, amountCreditedFrom TEXT ,transactionAmount double ,balance DOUBLE, currentTime timestamp , PRIMARY KEY((acctID, transactionDate), currentTime )) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (currentTime DESC);
```

This is my Looping code

```
@Override
public DemoModel save(DemoModel demoModel) {
    int i = 0;
    try {
        for (i = 0; i < 100000; i++) {
            Thread.sleep(2L);
            demoRepository.save(demoModel);
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("worked till " + i);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Before running the loop this was the stats provided by the Stress tool,

```
Keyspace : stress2
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms
    Write Count: 2
    Write Latency: 0.1565 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: demomodel
            SSTable count: 0
            Space used (live): 0 bytes
            Space used (total): 0 bytes
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0 bytes
            Off heap memory used (total): 342 bytes
            SSTable Compression Ratio: -1.0
            Number of partitions (estimate): 1
            Memtable cell count: 2
            Memtable data size: 266 bytes
            Memtable off heap memory used: 342 bytes
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 0
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 2
            Local write latency: 0.152 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Percent repaired: NaN
            Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
            Bytes unrepaired: 0.000KiB
            Bytes pending repair: 0.000KiB
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 0 bytes
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Index summary off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 0
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 0
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 0
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2.0
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Dropped Mutations: 0 bytes
            Failed Replication Count: null
```

After the completion of loop, this was the stats, as we can see memtable size have increased till 13 mb

```
Keyspace : stress2
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms
    Write Count: 100002
    Write Latency: 0.045491610167796646 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: demomodel
            SSTable count: 0
            Space used (live): 0 bytes
            Space used (total): 0 bytes
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0 bytes
            Off heap memory used (total): 13.26 MiB
            SSTable Compression Ratio: -1.0
            Number of partitions (estimate): 1
            Memtable cell count: 100002
            Memtable data size: 399 bytes
            Memtable off heap memory used: 13.26 MiB
            Memtable switch count: 0
            Local read count: 0
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 100002
            Local write latency: 0.045 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Percent repaired: NaN
            Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
            Bytes unrepaired: 0.000KiB
            Bytes pending repair: 0.000KiB
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 0 bytes
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Index summary off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 0
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 0
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 0
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2.0
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Dropped Mutations: 0 bytes
            Failed Replication Count: null
```

Now as I tried to flush, and expecting some data in Compacted partition, strangely there was very less data, here is the stats

```
Keyspace : stress2
    Read Count: 0
    Read Latency: NaN ms
    Write Count: 100002
    Write Latency: 0.045491610167796646 ms
    Pending Flushes: 0
            Table: demomodel
            SSTable count: 1
            Space used (live): 5.29 KiB
            Space used (total): 5.29 KiB
            Space used by snapshots (total): 0 bytes
            Off heap memory used (total): 8 bytes
            SSTable Compression Ratio: 0.5753424657534246
            Number of partitions (estimate): 1
            Memtable cell count: 0
            Memtable data size: 0 bytes
            Memtable off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Memtable switch count: 1
            Local read count: 0
            Local read latency: NaN ms
            Local write count: 100002
            Local write latency: 0.045 ms
            Pending flushes: 0
            Percent repaired: 0.0
            Bytes repaired: 0.000KiB
            Bytes unrepaired: 0.214KiB
            Bytes pending repair: 0.000KiB
            Bloom filter false positives: 0
            Bloom filter false ratio: 0.00000
            Bloom filter space used: 16 bytes
            Bloom filter off heap memory used: 8 bytes
            Index summary off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compression metadata off heap memory used: 0 bytes
            Compacted partition minimum bytes: 216
            Compacted partition maximum bytes: 258
            Compacted partition mean bytes: 258
            Average live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2.0
            Maximum live cells per slice (last five minutes): 2
            Average tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1.0
            Maximum tombstones per slice (last five minutes): 1
            Dropped Mutations: 0 bytes
            Failed Replication Count: null
```

Now atlast when i query the table, there were only 3 rows, but we can see the LocalWriteCount > 100000,

Here is my data model for the schema,

```
    package com.example.connectCass.Model;

import lombok.Data;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.cql.PrimaryKeyType;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.PrimaryKeyColumn;
import org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.mapping.Table;
import com.datastax.driver.core.LocalDate;


import java.util.Date;


@Data
@Table
public class DemoModel {

    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "acctID", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private String acctID;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "transactionDate", type = PrimaryKeyType.PARTITIONED)
    private LocalDate transactionDate;
    @PrimaryKeyColumn(name = "currentTime", type = PrimaryKeyType.CLUSTERED)
    private Date currentTime;

    @Column
    private String card;

    @Column
    private String amountCreditedFrom;

    @Column
    private double transactionAmount;

    @Column
    private double balance;

    public void setTransactionDate(){
        this.transactionDate =LocalDate.fromMillisSinceEpoch(new Date().getTime());
    }

    public void setCurrentTime(){
        this.currentTime = new Date();
    }
}
```

Can someone tell where I am going wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Well, this is your PARTITION KEY: `acctID, transactionDate`. If the `transactionDate` is the same, then my question is how many `acctID`s are you testing with?

Comment: acctID is just one, since my partion key would be mixed of `acctID, transactionDate` and whole primary key is having a current time stamp, so i think data wont be overwritten as primary key is everytime diff as ensured by a sleep of 2ms

Comment: Main reason was to test my partition size if 1,00,000 data is in one partition

Comment: Or is my understanding is wrong ?

Comment: It seems you are writing the same record 100000 times. I wonder why you got 3 rows and not just one. You should change accID or transactionDate for every write, if you want to write different records. Which raises the question "What do you intend to stress-test in the first place?". Do you want to see, how C* digests 100000 writes to the same record, or do you want to write 100000 different records and see C*'s reactions?

Comment: I don't see where you're updating the `currentTime` in your loop before the `save` (write) to Cassandra.  Wouldn't that cause all of the `currentTime`s to be the same?

Comment: I have added one more code where the model class is written, it will automatically give the current time if I am right.

Comment: Ok I got it, I found a bug in the code, thanks for the help, it really cleared things out, actually same object was being used multiple times, my bad.